# JComponents getting smaller in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm trying to create a Game of Life type of application, and I have some problems with drawing the cells. I have one large `JPanel` (`RectGridPanel`) acting as the ground for the simulation, and on that panel I draw out a grid by adding smaller panels (`GridElement`) in a `GridLayout`. Then I try to add my cells to these smaller panels.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GridElement extends JPanel
{
    
    public GridElement()
    {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    }
    
    public void createCell()
    {
        Cell newCell = new RectCell();
        this.add(newCell, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;

public class RectCell extends JPanel
{
    
    public RectCell()
    {
        
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class RectGridPanel extends JPanel
{   
    public RectGridPanel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(840, 800));
        
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(20,21));
        
        for(int x = 0; x < 21; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
            {
                GridElement element = new GridElement();
                element.createCell();
                this.add(element);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

What I want to achieve is that my cells (colored blue) fill out all those `GridElement` components I created, but in reality the coloring of the cells gets smaller in size the further they are from the top left corner:

[image]

Comment: Generally, you create one drawing JPanel and draw your cells.  The Oracle tutorial, [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) will show you how.  You can take a look at this version of [Conway's Game of Life](https://github.com/ggleblanc2/conways-life).

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: BTW: I had a few moments spare so turned that into runnable code (an MRE) here. There is a compilation error that needed to be fixed (`Cell newCell = new RectCell();` -> `RectCell newCell = new RectCell();`) before it could compile, and then .. It appeared fine for me. This is [how it appears shrunken down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrSOR.png). **Note:** to avoid wasting your time, and more importantly, the time of others helping for free, **be sure to check your MRE code actually *shows* the error.**

Comment: Yeah didn't notice that, but that is just my mistake in reducing the code (RectCell extends cell). Also that is exactly the behaivour I'm looking for, but mine still looks disrupted.

Comment: 1) You have too many levels of components. All you need is a "GridCell" to represent each component and a "GridPanel" to hold all the GridCells in a grid layout. I'm guessing because you have a panel containing a panel containing a panel you have a layout issue.  2) Don't use `setPreferredSize()` on your "GridPanel". The layout manager will determine the size based on the components added to the panel.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned it makes no sense to nest components with so many levels and to define sizes when using GridLayout.
The shifting of the blue rect is caused by code you didn't post. Seems the variables x and y have influence of the position which makes no sense.
Here a almoste MRB how easily your first target can be achieved:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel basePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20,21));
    int cols = 21, rows = 20;
    Dimension dimension = new Dimension(30, 30);

    for (int i=0; i<rows*cols; i++) {
        final int number = i;
        JPanel square = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()) {
            {
                this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
                this.add(new JLabel(String.valueOf(number), SwingConstants.CENTER));
                this.setPreferredSize(dimension);
            }
        };
        basePanel.add(square);
    }

    frame.add(basePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Instead of the anonymous inner class used to define the tiles you of couse can extract this to a own class extending JPanel.

Comment: *As mentioned it makes no sense ... to define sizes when using GridLayout*. It has nothing to do with the GridLayout. It applies to all layout managers. Don't use setBounds(). You don't know what the size of the frame should be because you don't know what the size of the decorations (border, title bar) should be for your LAF. You just defeated the purpose of using layout managers. Instead, you should `pack()` the frame before making it visible (and after all the components have been added to the frame.

Comment: Yes, correct. old habbits because I'm only using undecorated frames. Changed the code so that the "empty" squares (when removing the labels used for demo) and the frame get a preferred size and are diplayed when running it.

Comment: Even if you use undecorated frames you should NOT set the size/bounds. The pack() method will do the work for you.